Problem with @misc citation keys in bib file
I am having trouble with the keyword arguments in a @misc citation, more specifically how its keys are defined. Does someone know the problem with it?
@misc{CABRAL123,
  Author = {Umberlandia Cabral},
  Date-Added = {2024-04-09 18:58:06 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2015-04-27 22:43:06 +0000},
  Howpublished = {IBGE},
  Keywords = {wiki},
  Title = {Sistema de Indicadores Culturais: Pais tem quase 40% da população em municipios sem salas de cinema},
  Url = {https://agenciadenoticias.ibge.gov.br/agencia-noticias/2012-agencia-de-noticias/noticias/26239-pais-tem-quase-40-da-populacao-em-municipios-sem-salas-de-cinema},
  Urlaccessdate = {10 abr 2024},
  Year = {2019},
  Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://agenciadenoticias.ibge.gov.br/agencia-noticias/2012-agencia-de-noticias/noticias/26239-pais-tem-quase-40-da-populacao-em-municipios-sem-salas-de-cinema}
}

This is my first post so thanks for the patience...
When I compile the document shows (??) in the document and in the logs:
Citation `CABRAL123' on page 1 undefined on input line 210.

‪./main.tex, 210‬
You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.
Learn more

I am not having any problem with any other references, I am theorizing it's something wrong with key names or date values, but nothing apparent at all.

Welcome! I see no problem in how the entry is coded and can't guess what your issue is. Can you please be more specific?

If you get question marks instead of citations in your document, you are using a BibTeX-based citation/bibliography setup and not biblatex (in which case you'd get the bold entry key if citations don't work). Often the problem is that BibTeX/Biber is not run correctly. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. But as cfr says, the % could also be problematic (more so with biblatex than with BibTeX).

I can't reproduce the problem you report with either BibTeX or Biblatex. However, I do get the wrong result with the former and compilation failure with the latter.
You need to escape the % in the title so that when LaTeX reads the .bbl it doesn't ignore the rest of the line. In Biblatex's case, you end up losing the closing curly bracket so the entry never ends, causing the standard runaway error. In BibTeX's case, you don't lose the end of the field, but you do lose a chunk in the middle, so the entry is typeset with the wrong title.
To fix it, just use \%.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{CABRAL123,
  Author = {Umberlandia Cabral},
  Date-Added = {2024-04-09 18:58:06 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2015-04-27 22:43:06 +0000},
  Howpublished = {IBGE},
  Keywords = {wiki},
  Title = {Sistema de Indicadores Culturais: Pais tem quase 40\% da população em municipios sem salas de cinema},
  Url = {https://agenciadenoticias.ibge.gov.br/agencia-noticias/2012-agencia-de-noticias/noticias/26239-pais-tem-quase-40-da-populacao-em-municipios-sem-salas-de-cinema},
  Urlaccessdate = {10 abr 2024},
  Year = {2019},
  Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://agenciadenoticias.ibge.gov.br/agencia-noticias/2012-agencia-de-noticias/noticias/26239-pais-tem-quase-40-da-populacao-em-municipios-sem-salas-de-cinema}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}

\cite{CABRAL123}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

If this isn't the problem, note that the issue could be with the previous entry in the .bib file as this is a common cause of errors generating not-quite-right messages.
[Images are reserved due to an Okular bug which shows no sign of getting itself fixed. Apologies for the lack of eye candy.]

Thanks!!! That was exactly the problem!!!!!!

@Fernando Please consider accepting the answer so people know the problem is solved and there's a solution here. You do this by clicking on the greyed-out tick/checkmark symbol at the top left of the answer you want to accept. (Disclaimer: accepting my answer will give me 'points'. It will also give you some. You can't buy anything with them, but if you get enough they'll eventually let you click other buttons. You may realise I don't work in advertising.)
